# Sacar texto con delimitador de un .txt y guardarlo en una variable (Batch Windows)

Tags: windows, batch

Buenas a tod@s el problema en si es que necesito ***sacar la ip*** de esta linea y guardarla en una variable (***solo la IP*** 4 octetos, ya podria ser esa ip o una como 192.168.100.2). [image: Archivo txt de la ip]

Tengo el siguiente archivo .bat;

```
@echo off
echo            ============================
echo            = CONFIGURACION DEL EQUIPO =
echo            ============================
echo\
echo  Fecha de hoy: %date% 
echo.
echo  Nombre del Equipo: %computername% 
echo.
echo  Direccion IP: 
    ipconfig | find /i "IPv4"
    ipconfig | find /i "IPv4" >> ip.txt

echo.
echo  MAC del Equipo:
    getmac  
echo.
echo FECHA : %date% HORA : %time% NOMBRE DEL EQUIPO : %computername% >> info.txt

echo\
echo  Presione la tecla "SPACE" para cerrar esta ventana...
pause > nul
```

Que lo que me da es información basica del equipo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que quiero es la Ip para añadirsela a el archivo al archivo que redirecciono como "info.txt" que se muestra de la siguiente manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Resumiendo quiero obtener la string que va desde ":" en adelante y guardarla en una variable.
Gracias de antemano.**

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el comando [for /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) para ejecutar el código que te interese y recuperar el valor.

Sería algo como esto:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=:" %%f in (`ipconfig ^| find /i "IPv4"`) do set ip=%%f

echo %ip%
```

La primera linea ejecuta `ipconfig | find /i "IPv4"`y se lo devuelve al comando for que lo trocea en partes usando el separador `:`. La parte que te interesa es la segunda donde está la IP. En la parte de `DO`se asigna a una variable que uses para guardar la IP.

En el caso de que tengas mas de una IP, te devolverá la última.

Espero que te sirva.